# Linux:How to hibernate after a period of sleep

Tags: linux, suspend

One of the windows features I miss in linux is the following: In windows you close the notebook lid and the system suspends to RAM, after a while (configurable) the computer automatically wakes up and proceed to suspend to disk.
I know that in linux exists suspend2both mode but that works suspending to disk just before running out of battery which is what I'm trying to avoid.

EDIT: More detailed answer found after searching with the answer data

https://askubuntu.com/questions/12383/how-to-go-automatically-from-suspend-into-hibernate

EDIT2: Those are the steps I've followed using Ubuntu 11.04 on a MSI Wind U100.

First: I've installed tuxonice because hibernation wasn't working on my netbook. As a side-effect the hibernation and wake-up processes are quite fast and very stable. The only drawback is that the display on hibernate/resume is in text-mode.
The easiest way to install tuxonice is by adding the corresponding ppa: https://launchpad.net/~tuxonice/+archive/ppa

Once you have hibernation working this script does all the magic

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script name: /etc/pm/sleep.d/00rtchibernate
# Purpose: Auto hibernates after a period of sleep
# Edit the "autohibernate" variable below to set the number of seconds to sleep.
curtime=$(date +%s)
autohibernate=7200
echo "$curtime $1" >>/tmp/autohibernate.log
if [ "$1" = "suspend" ]
then
    # Suspending.  Record current time, and set a wake up timer.
    echo "$curtime" >/var/run/pm-utils/locks/rtchibernate.lock
    rtcwake -m no -s $autohibernate
fi

if [ "$1" = "resume" ]
then
    # Coming out of sleep
    sustime=$(cat /var/run/pm-utils/locks/rtchibernate.lock)
    rm /var/run/pm-utils/locks/rtchibernate.lock
    # Did we wake up due to the rtc timer above?
    if [ $(($curtime - $sustime)) -ge $autohibernate ]
    then
        # Then hibernate
        rm /var/run/pm-utils/locks/pm-suspend.lock
        /usr/sbin/pm-hibernate
    else
        # Otherwise cancel the rtc timer and wake up normally.
        rtcwake -m no -s 1
    fi
fi
```

By modifying the autohibernate value you change the sleep time after which the machine will wake-up and go instantly into hibernation

NOTE: You may have to install rtcwake, I had already installed but I can't remember if I've installed the package myself.

Comment: Suspend2Both actually does the hibernation (what you're calling "suspend to disk") immediately, but it doesn't shut down until the battery is very low.

Comment: Throw in an SSD, and then only suspend to disk: problem solved. Not solved cheaply, but solved nonetheless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For other distros like CentOS or Fedor or Redhat which uses `systemd`. We need to change the location of script instead of placing it in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` place it in `/usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` as `0000rtchibernate.sh` use `chmod +x` to make it executable.

Finally, few tweaks are required in the script as well to make it compatible with `systemd`. For sake of simplicity I am giving the complete re-writen script

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script name: /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/0000rtchibernate
# Purpose: Auto hibernates after a period of sleep
# Edit the "autohibernate" variable below to set the number of seconds to sleep.
curtime=$(date +%s)
autohibernate=3600 #number is second
lock=/tmp/rtchibernate.lock
echo "$curtime $1" >>/tmp/autohibernate.log
if [ "$1" = "pre" ]
then
    # Suspending.  Record current time, and set a wake up timer.
    echo "$curtime" > $lock
    rtcwake -m no -s $autohibernate
fi

if [ "$1" = "post" ]
then
    # Coming out of sleep
    sustime=`cat $lock`
    rm $lock
    # Did we wake up due to the rtc timer above?
    if [ $(($curtime - $sustime)) -ge $autohibernate ]
    then
        # Then hibernate
        systemctl hibernate
    else
        # Otherwise cancel the rtc timer and wake up normally.
        rtcwake -m no -s 1
    fi
fi
```

The `autohibernate` variable is in seconds change it as seem fit.I hope I have helped

Answer (score 4):

I'd guess what you'd want is something like http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/8/rtcwake/ which could be used instead of the default S2R (AKA sleep) program. This could then wake the machine if it has been asleep for more than (say) 20 minutes and trigger a hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to `chmod +x` that file, making it executable.

There's another solution without `rtcwake`, using `wakealarm` in `/sys/class/rtc/rtc0`. Make use obsolete code in pm-functions (`/usr/lib/pm-utils`) after the comments #since the kernel does not directly support ... , ('cos the current kernel (after 3.6 something) does directly support). Revert that code and put in `do_suspend()` part instead of `do_suspend_hybrid()`.

Obsolete code (suspend then hibernate when suspend_hybrid is called):

```
# since the kernel does not directly support hybrid sleep, we do
# something else -- suspend and schedule an alarm to go into
# hibernate if we have slept long enough.
# Only do this if we do not need to do any special video hackery on resume
# from hibernate, though.
if [ -z "$SUSPEND_HYBRID_MODULE" -a -w "$PM_RTC/wakealarm" ] && \
    check_suspend && check_hibernate && ! is_set $HIBERNATE_RESUME_POST_VIDEO; \
    then
    SUSPEND_HYBRID_MODULE="kernel"
    do_suspend_hybrid() {
    WAKETIME=$(( $(cat "$PM_RTC/since_epoch") + PM_HIBERNATE_DELAY))
    echo >"$PM_RTC/wakealarm"
    echo $WAKETIME > "$PM_RTC/wakealarm"
    if do_suspend; then
        NOW=$(cat "$PM_RTC/since_epoch")
        if [ "$NOW" -ge "$WAKETIME" -a "$NOW" -lt $((WAKETIME + 30)) ]; then
        log "Woken by RTC alarm, hibernating."
        # if hibernate fails for any reason, go back to suspend.
        do_hibernate || do_suspend
        else
        echo > "$PM_RTC/wakealarm"
        fi
    else
        # if we cannot suspend, just try to hibernate.
        do_hibernate
    fi
    }
fi
```

Recommended. Even easier to use `uswsusp` while the same time maximize the benefit of `s2both` i.e. `s2both when suspend`. Put the reverted code in `do_suspend()` part of `uswsusp` module (`/usr/lib/pm-utils/module.d`).

Reverted code (suspend_hybrid when suspend is called):

```
WAKETIME=$(( $(cat "$PM_RTC/since_epoch") + PM_HIBERNATE_DELAY))
echo >"$PM_RTC/wakealarm"
echo $WAKETIME > "$PM_RTC/wakealarm"
if do_suspend_hybrid; then
    NOW=$(cat "$PM_RTC/since_epoch")
    if [ "$NOW" -ge "$WAKETIME" -a "$NOW" -lt $((WAKETIME + 30)) ];             then
    log "Woken by RTC alarm, hibernating."
    # if hibernate fails for any reason, go back to suspend_hybrid.
    do_hibernate || do_suspend_hybrid
    else
    echo > "$PM_RTC/wakealarm"
    fi
else
    # when do_suspend is being called, convert to suspend_hybrid.
    do_suspend_hybrid
fi
```

With `uswsusp`, we can see the progress of suspend/hibernate and the reverse process displayed in text, even we can abort it by pressing backspace. Without `uswsusp`, suspend/hibernate just appear-disappear annoyingly, especially when `wakealarm` is triggered and execute `hibernate` (`s2disk` in uswsusp). Set the period of sleep before hibernate in the usual place on `pm-functions` file.

```
# variables to handle hibernate after suspend support
PM_HIBERNATE_DELAY=900  # 15 minutes
PM_RTC=/sys/class/rtc/rtc0
```

Here's the `uswsusp` mod: (remember, this module is called from `pm-functions` so the inserted variables are the same)

```
#!/bin/sh

# disable processing of 90chvt and 99video.
# s2ram and s2disk handle all this stuff internally.
uswsusp_hooks()
{
    disablehook 99video "disabled by uswsusp"
}

# Since we disabled 99video, we need to take responsibility for proper
# quirk handling.  s2ram handles all common video quirks internally,
# so all we have to do is translate the HAL standard options to s2ram options.
uswsusp_get_quirks()
{
    OPTS=""
    ACPI_SLEEP=0
    for opt in $PM_CMDLINE; do
        case "${opt##--quirk-}" in # just quirks, please
            dpms-on)       ;; # no-op
            dpms-suspend)      ;; # no-op
            radeon-off)        OPTS="$OPTS --radeontool" ;;
            reset-brightness)  ;; # no-op
            s3-bios)       ACPI_SLEEP=$(($ACPI_SLEEP + 1)) ;;
            s3-mode)       ACPI_SLEEP=$(($ACPI_SLEEP + 2)) ;;
            vbe-post)      OPTS="$OPTS --vbe_post" ;;
            vbemode-restore)   OPTS="$OPTS --vbe_mode" ;;
            vbestate-restore)  OPTS="$OPTS --vbe_save" ;;
            vga-mode-3)        ;; # no-op
            save-pci)          OPTS="$OPTS --pci_save" ;;
            none)          QUIRK_NONE="true" ;;
            *) continue ;;
        esac
    done
    [ $ACPI_SLEEP -ne 0 ] && OPTS="$OPTS --acpi_sleep $ACPI_SLEEP"
    # if we were told to ignore quirks, do so.
    # This is arguably not the best way to do things, but...
    [ "$QUIRK_NONE" = "true" ] && OPTS=""
}

# Since we disabled 99video, we also need to handle displaying
# help info for the quirks we handle.
uswsusp_help()
{
    echo  # first echo makes it look nicer.
    echo "s2ram video quirk handler options:"
    echo
    echo "  --quirk-radeon-off"
    echo "  --quirk-s3-bios"
    echo "  --quirk-s3-mode"
    echo "  --quirk-vbe-post"
    echo "  --quirk-vbemode-restore"
    echo "  --quirk-vbestate-restore"
    echo "  --quirk-save-pci"
    echo "  --quirk-none"
}

# This idiom is used for all sleep methods.  Only declare the actual
# do_ method if:
# 1: some other sleep module has not already done so, and
# 2: this sleep method can actually work on this system.
#
# For suspend, if SUSPEND_MODULE is set then something else has already
# implemented do_suspend.  We could just check to see of do_suspend was
# already declared using command_exists, but using a dedicated environment
# variable makes it easier to debug when we have to know what sleep module
# ended up claiming ownership of a given sleep method.
if [ -z "$SUSPEND_MODULE" ] && command_exists s2ram && \
    ( grep -q mem /sys/power/state || \
        ( [ -c /dev/pmu ] && check_suspend_pmu; ); ); then
    SUSPEND_MODULE="uswsusp"
    do_suspend()
    {
        WAKETIME=$(( $(cat "$PM_RTC/since_epoch") + PM_HIBERNATE_DELAY))
        echo >"$PM_RTC/wakealarm"
        echo $WAKETIME > "$PM_RTC/wakealarm"
        if do_suspend_hybrid; then
            NOW=$(cat "$PM_RTC/since_epoch")
            if [ "$NOW" -ge "$WAKETIME" -a "$NOW" -lt $((WAKETIME + 30)) ]; then
            log "Woken by RTC alarm, hibernating."
            # if hibernate fails for any reason, go back to suspend_hybrid.
            do_hibernate || do_suspend_hybrid
            else
            echo > "$PM_RTC/wakealarm"
            fi
        else
            # when do_suspend is being called, convert to suspend_hybrid.
            do_suspend_hybrid
        fi      
    }
fi

if [ -z "$HIBERNATE_MODULE" ] && \
    [ -f /sys/power/disk ] && \
    grep -q disk /sys/power/state && \
    [ -c /dev/snapshot ] &&
    command_exists s2disk; then
    HIBERNATE_MODULE="uswsusp"
    do_hibernate()
    {
        s2disk
    }
fi

if [ -z "$SUSPEND_HYBRID_MODULE" ] && 
    grep -q mem /sys/power/state && \
    command_exists s2both && \
    check_hibernate; then
    SUSPEND_HYBRID_MODULE="uswsusp"
    do_suspend_hybrid()
    {   
        uswsusp_get_quirks
        s2both --force $OPTS 
    }
    if [ "$METHOD" = "suspend_hybrid" ]; then
        add_before_hooks uswsusp_hooks
        add_module_help uswsusp_help
    fi
fi
```